# Hoisting Formik values to higher level state

Tags: reactjs, use-state, formik

In a Formik component, I need one of the values from the values prop to be available outside of the component. Preferably bound to a state variable.

```
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={LocationAddressSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {({ isSubmitting, isValid, values }) => (
          <Form>
```

How can I take what comes back from values.name for example and set it to a state variable so that every time the value of values.name changes the state will re render holding that new value

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way?

```html
<Formik ...>
...

<input type="text" onChange={props.handleChange} ...>
...
</Formik>
```